# If the first D note (in the 1st beam) is flat, does that mean the next D note (in the 2nd beam) is also flat? (see photo)

Tags: notation, beaming

If the first D note (in the 1st beam) is flat, does that mean the next D note (in the 2nd beam) is also flat? (see photo)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is flat because it's in the same bar, and the same octave.

A D on a different octave, on the other hand, would not be flattened by that initial flat.

Answer (score 0):

An accidental in any bar will always and only affect the pitch concerned. So, here, any other D note *in that bar only at that same pitch* will be affected by the accidental (here, a flat sign). The very next barline will cancel *any* accidentals that occurred in the previous bar.